# What is the best suited type for big numbers?

Tags: julia, bigint

I would like to create a unique transaction ids, IBANs randomly in julia.
I arrived range of transaction ids in [0:10^58] per millennium as IBAN domain is [A-Z]{2}[0-9]{32} or [A-Z]{34} (ie. max 10^51) and assume max 10 txns per day per account.

Whether should I select transaction id type as String or Bigint and their pros and cons in txn processing system and decision support systems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Mathieu_B's suggestion of using UUIDs makes sense but if you prefer something strictly numerical, you can use `UInt128`s easily as well:

```
julia> rand(UInt128)
0xa62ff810bcd06e644f5df0a64611cc0b
```

The number of bits in a UUID and a UInt128 are the same, so this should be at least as unique as UUIDs generated by `uuid4()` (i.e. randomly). The main benefit of UUIDs is that there are other methods implemented, should you need to use them:

- `uuid1`: based on date-time and MAC address
- `uuid4`: random/pseudo-random
- `uuid5`: hash-based

Answer (score 6):

If what you are looking for is an identifier, systems like [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) may be more appropriate. In Julia, the `UUIDs` module from the standard library can help:

```
julia> using UUIDs: uuid4

julia> import Random

julia> Random.seed!(43);

julia> uuid4()
UUID("7d6398a5-f5bb-4164-8552-1668b964e46f")

julia> uuid4()
UUID("93938d68-980f-40b1-b1f9-789c5230116c")
```

Comparing with UUIDs is faster than with `String`, and about the same as `BigInt`. Here is a quick benchmark using [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl), the `setup` part is not taken into account for runtime estimation:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools: @btime

julia> @btime s1 == s2 setup=(s1=string(uuid4()); s2=string(uuid4()))
  5.685 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime s1 == s2 setup=(s1=uuid4(); s2=uuid4())
  1.640 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime s1 == s2 setup=(s1=BigInt(rand(Int)); s2=BigInt(rand(Int)))
  2.976 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```